# irreducibility of minimal polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose degree of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ is relatively prime to $\beta$ over $F$ then prove that minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $F$ is irreducible over $F(\alpha)$.

I suppose it will be very easy, but I am not able to find. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Relate the degrees of all those minimal polynomials to degrees of field extensions, and
2. Calculate the degree of the extension $F(\alpha,\beta)/F$ in two different ways using the multiplicativity of the extension degree in a tower of fields.
3. Pay extra attention to the divisibility relations you get in step 2 and the given assumptions.

Tauno Metsänkylä (my former teacher): "Don't underestimate the power of a (trivial looking) result that counts something."